# Difference in ownership pattern in List and Queue

Tags: java, multithreading, collections

From the code, it seems that there is a difference in the way ownership of members is handled in the case of a `LinkedList` and `ArayBlockingQueue`.
(It may be the same in others too  - but as of now I am focussing only on the above.)

While in the case of `ArrayBlockingQueue`, the ownership seems to be transferred from the input thread to the extracting thread - in `LinkedList`, the thread that puts in an object, maintains a reference to it even after it has been retrieved by a separate thread(potentially).

Is my understanding correct?
Why do we have this difference in behaviour?
(Here I am using instance and thread synonymously,as an instance would be running in a particular thread.)

Comment: Some piece of code could be useful to understand your problem!

Comment: Please refer to JDK for the respective classes

Answer (score 2):

`LinkedList` does not provide any thread safety or synchronization at all. You are responsible for doing that yourself.

The `concurrent` package collections do provide thread safety on the collection itself, you are still responsible for managing any modifications you might make to objects within the collection though.

There is no concept of "ownership" of objects in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Watching Oracle documentation:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html
  You can read that they are different about thread safety.

The first one is inside cuncurrent subpackege.
In the second (LinkedList) you can read "Note that this implementation is not synchronized".

This should be the cause of the differences you are observing.